# Join with sqlite on table in android

Tags: sqlite

Given a table like:

```
object    subject    ID      parentID
------    -------   -----    --------
  A         NULL      1          0
  B         NULL      2          0
  C         NULL      3          0
  D         NULL      4          0
  E         NULL      5          0
 Null        CC       6          1
 Null        DD       7          2
 Null        EE       8          2
```

I need a query with good performance that returns the following result:

```
result
------
  A
  CC
  B
  DD
  EE
```

Comment: Please explain what this query should do; in particular, why C/D/E are not returned, and how deep the recursion can go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use coalesce, it's a function that returns its leftmost non-null argument:

```
select coalesce(object, subject) 
from t;
```

Coalesce is a shorter form of:

```
select case when object is not null then object else subject end
from t;
```

Comment: This query returns eight rows.

Comment: Yes, I'm unable to guess what would filter out certain rows so I assumed that the expected result is uncomplete